# Testing the exception message for ActionController::BadRequest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, minitest

I'm trying to test a controller that raises a `ActionController::BadRequest` exception under various scenarios. Each scenario provides a specific message to the log.

To test, I get a passing test if I write:

```rb
test "should raise exception due to missing Data A" do
  post comment_path
  assert_response :bad_request
end
```

However, the `:bad_request` can be due to many things. I'd like to test the value of the exception message is what is expect. Is there a way I can access that?

If I try to rewrite the test as follows, the result is: **ActionController::BadRequest expected but nothing was raised**:

```rb
test "should raise exception due to missing Data A" do
  exception = assert_raise ActionController::BadRequest do
    post comment_path
  end
  assert_equal 'Missing Data A', exception.message
end
```

I don't understand why it's saying "nothing was raised". In the controller, the call is literally:

```rb
raise(ActionController::BadRequest.new(), "Missing Data A")
```

Is there a way I can test whether the exception message is what's expected?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to test the exception message using:

```rb
test "should raise exception due to missing Data A" do
  post comment_path
  assert_response :bad_request
  assert response.body.include?('Missing Data A')
end
```